# How can I get dev tools (such as make) for Mac OS X via the command line

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, curl, makefile

I am in a bit of a pickle.  I have a few Mac Minis that I am colocating at my ISP and only have shell access (via ssh for example) to administer the boxes.  This is fine, but I just realized - after downloading some tar files for a couple of packages I needed - that I don't have the basic dev tools installed (such as make, for compiling source code).  Is there a place I can download them from using curl?

Thanks in advance!
~Aki

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't use VNC to install XCode the normal way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install xcode off of the Mac OS install media (I think it's the second dvd or cd or whatever, but am unsure).  That should do it

Comment: Thanks Ben. Remember, the machines are remote, and I do not have access to GUI tools - it has to all be over ssh, and the shell.  Does Apple have this downloadable as binaries that I can get using curl?

Comment: that makes things much more difficult.  I imagine they exist somewhere on the apple website.  Once you get the dmgs, hdiutil will probably be necessary http://macosx.com/tech-support/how-to-install-a-dmg-file-at-a-command-line/7989.html

Answer (score 1):

Install [MacPorts](http://macports.org). This will give you all the usual command line tools that you might need.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Is this installable as a binary via the terminal?  Remember, the machines are remote, and I do not have access to GUI tools - it has to all be over ssh, and the shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) to get yourself a copy of lynx (command line web browser) and then use that to download the OS X developer tools from [Apple](http://connect.apple.com).  Or you could just install a GNU tool chain from Fink iteslf.

Comment: Nice.  I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks Grant.

Answer (score 0):

You should already have `curl` (mine is at `/usr/bin/curl`) which you can use to get the [`fink`](http://www.finkproject.org/) or [`MacPorts`](http://www.macports.org/) downloads. Then go from there.

I'm a fink guy myself. Fink will need the devtools DVD isntalled.